# Sql join in other and other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get results from other table using LEFT JOIN.
I want to show user location using Join.

My database looks like this:

**User table:**

```
#ID   |  location_id | email | pass
------------------------------------
  1   |   1          | ...    | ....
```

Locataion table:

```
#ID   |  county_id   | city_id | user_id
------------------------------------------
  1   |   1          |  1      |    2
```

**Coutnries table:**

```
#ID   |  name     |  
-------------------
  1   |  Usa
  2   |  Belgium
  3   |  Serbia
```

**Cities table:**

```
 #ID   |  name     |  
-------------------
  1   |  Berlin
  2   |  London
  3   |  New Your
```

Comment: what is your expected output? have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join two mysql tables with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172411/join-two-mysql-tables-with-php)

Comment: I really hope that's a typo in the `coutnries` and not the real table name.  Otherwise you will annoy developers and those that maintain this table for years to come.  Same for `Locataion`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
select * from usertable as a
join locataion as b on a.location_id=b.id
left join Coutnries as c on b.County_id = c.id
left join cities as d on b.City_id= d.id
```