# how to Join two mysql tables in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two table where I want to query with join two table.
If there is pro_pic = 'NULL' than the result I want to get without null pro_pic.

Here is the Table:

user_info

```
 ID    user_id       full_name  country
 --------------------------------------
 1      Star01         Sagor     Us
 2      Star02         Rofiq     India
 3      Star03         Karim     Aus
```

pro_pic

```
ID   user_id  pro_pic  
--------------------------------- 
 1   Star01  14523.png  
 2   Star02  NULL   
 3   Star03  554513.png
```

so I want to result like

```
ID    user_id       full_name        country            pro_pic  
 ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 1     Star01        Sagor            Us               14523.png  
 3     Star03        Karim            Aus               554513.png
```

the null pro_pic field not showing.

Here is my query but I didn't got the result :'(

```
<?php

$stmt1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ui.user_id, pp.pro_pic, pp.user_id, 
ui.full_name, ui.country
FROM user_info
INNER JOIN pro_pic ON ui.user_id=pp.user_id where ui.show_hide_profile != '1' and pp.pro_pic != '' limit $current, $limit");


while($user_info = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt1)){

echo $user_id_view = $user_info['user_id'];
echo $full_name = $user_info['full_name'];
echo $country = $user_info['country'];
echo $pro_pic = $user_info['pro_pic'];

}

?>
```

Please help me thanks to all

Comment: What result did you get instead? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And why is there a row for Star02 anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
   $stmt1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ui.user_id, pp.pro_pic, pp.user_id, ui.full_name, ui.country
        FROM user_info ui
        INNER JOIN pro_pic pp ON ui.user_id=pp.user_id where pp.pro_pic IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY ui.user_id  limit $current, $limit");
```

EDIT: Added order by clause 
Please note whenever you use limit clause you should use order by clause because if you are not using order by clause the MySQL result always return random rows

Comment: @pothharapothik please see I have updated my answer added with order by caluse

Answer (score -1):

Use this query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM citys LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.city=citys.city WHERE citys.id=$id";
```

Here are the link to the code:

[Join two mysql tables with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172411/join-two-mysql-tables-with-php)

Hope it helps.