# Query to fetch data from two different tables

Tags: php

I have two tables. Table A and B. 
I have a log-in form where I will get the username,password, assign, assign2 of the user from table A and fetch data depending on the user's assign1 and assign2 from table B.

How my query would look like?
Looking for answers. Thankyou so much.

```
Table A -THIS IS THE TABLE FOR LOG-IN FORM
==========================================
username | password | assign1 | assign2 |
------------------------------------------
SANDRA   | SANTOS   |    1    |   1     | //Values
--------------------------------------------

Table B - 
=======================================

name | assign1 | assign 2 |
------------------------------
DADA |  1      |   1      |  //this will be displayed
------------------------------
gorg |  2      |    2     |
```

//this must not be displayed since the user assign1 and assign2 who logged in did not match to this

Comment: Did you code something ?

Comment: SHow the 2 tables' structure and data

Comment: This is way too broad, voting for close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql join two table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171963/sql-join-two-table)

Comment: [edit] your question. __Do not__ post code in comments.

Comment: please add table structure too

Comment: You obviously don't understand how to use this code. What is `$con`? What are the arguments to `mysqli_query`? (hint - open a manual). Second hint - __learn debugging__.

Comment: I already added the table structure. Thankyou

Comment: You added table structure, but deleted the code. __[Edit] again__.

Comment: I seriously don't have an idea how to code that particular task to achieve the result I want. That's why I am looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using $sql variable in

> $result = $con->query($sql);

It should be $queryagain.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are very very new to database programing. First of all I recomend you to read https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp this page and work on examples using try it yourself part.

Join Types:

INNER JOIN: Returns records that have matching values in both tables. That means if  assign field is filled in Table A and the value is included in table B then this type of join should match the rows.

LEFT JOIN: Return all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table. That means all rows in Table A will match either the value is included in table B or not.

RIGHT JOIN: Return all records from the right table, and the matched records from the left table. That means all rows in Table B will match either the value is included in table A or not.

FULL JOIN: Return all records when there is a match in either left or right table. All rows in table A and table B will be included in te result set either they match or not.

Your SQL query may look like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b on a.assign1 = b.assign1 INNER JOIN table_b b2 on  a.assign2 = b2.assign2";
```

execution part of the sql can be different depending your database engine or other libraries.

I think this thread also helps you: [Join two mysql tables with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172411/join-two-mysql-tables-with-php)

Comment: it looks like you are "very very new" to SQL if you think your query will return something near the OP asked. It will just return nothing in the actual state.

Comment: question didn't include such detailed information at first state. Table structures, column names etc added by edit.

Comment: ok than its preferable to wait for additional info, which I did.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but if you want to fetch data from `Table B` which depends on `assign1` and `assign2` you can do it like this:

```
$queryagain = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tableB INNER JOIN tableA ON tableB.name=tableA.username WHERE tableA.assign1 = tableB.assign1 AND tableA.assign2 = tableB.assign2");
```

When you use `JOIN` it's best practice to `JOIN` by primary key (id). If `tableB.name=tableA.username` are not columns with same value you can join by other columns, like assign1, or assign2:

**assign1:**

```
$queryagain = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tableB INNER JOIN tableA ON tableB.assign1=tableA.assign1 WHERE tableA.assign2 = tableB.assign2");
```

**assign2:**

```
$queryagain = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tableB INNER JOIN tableA ON tableB.assign2=tableA.assign2 WHERE tableA.assign1 = tableB.assign1");
```

Notice: Where clause is not necessay, you can edit WHERE clause depends of the result you want.